# jQuery val() doesn't update value in .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an HTML page generated with some default values for input fields. Here is the HTML and JavaScript:

```js
$('#trigger').click(function () {
            var content = $(this).parent().find('.content');
            content.find('#name').val("Young man");
            content.find('#age').val("25");

            alert(content.find('#name').val());
            alert(content.html());
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
        <a id="trigger" href="#">Know!</a>
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" value="dummy">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" value="dummy">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the div assigned to a variable, then change the values of `name` and `age` through this handle. The first alert method confirms that they are changed. But why is `content.html()` still outputs the original html? How can I make `html()` output the updated data?

Comment: This code snippet shows that you havent loaded jquery? Have you included jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the new value using `attr()`.

```js
$('#trigger').click(function () {
            var content = $(this).parent().find('.content');
            content.find('#name').attr("value", "Young man");
            content.find('#age').attr("value", "25");

            console.log(content.find('#name').val());
            console.log(content.html());
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
        <a id="trigger" href="#">Know!</a>
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" value="dummy">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" value="dummy">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery `.val()` method never updates the `value` attribute. You can change it with `.attr()` method.

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  var content = $(this).parent().find('.content');
  content.find('#name').attr("value", "Young man");
  content.find('#age').attr("value", "25");

  alert(content.find('#name').val());
  alert(content.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <a id="trigger" href="#">Know!</a>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Age:</label>
      <input type="text" id="age" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```